# Taking Credit Cards Inside a Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook, ssl

Tell me if this is a) possible and b) allowed.

I'd like to build a checkout page that takes credit cards and processes them inside Facebook, specifically inside a dedicated Facebook app that will be built for this.

Can I just put this in an iFrame with SSL in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem unless you're working with game in app purchase.  Then FB requires you to use FB credits.  As long as you can offer up the link securely you should be fine.